# Phenom II X4 955 BE work in socket AM3+?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, amd-phenom, processor-socket

On the [AMD spec page](http://products.amd.com/pages/DesktopCPUDetail.aspx?id=532&f1=&f2=&f3=&f4=&f5=&f6=&f7=&f8=&f9=&f10=&f11=&f12=), this CPU shows it works only on socket AM3.

Will it work in a socket AM3+?

Are AM3 and AM3+ different or the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AM3+ is actually a modified AM3 Socket which was designed for future CPUs which will use the new Bulldozer microarchitecture.

AM3+ sockets fully compatible with AM3 processors.

Comment: I hope you're right. Or I come back and kill u  LOL. Some of the better boards available are socket AM3+ so I'm going to order one.

Comment: Now I start being worried... :) Anyway, you're welcome to cross check me on Wiki at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM3%2B#Socket_AM3.2B where stated: 
"AM3+ is a modification of the AM3 Socket designed for future "Zambezi" CPUs which use the new Bulldozer microarchitecture and will retain compatibility with AM3 processors."